# Creating a tornado plot with PGFPlots and force a break in one of the horizontal bars

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

To display a sensitivity analysis I want to produce a [Tornado plot](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/42391/versions/2/screenshot.png). In the plot a specific base case value is compared to the values produced after changing parameters in the model. I started from this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47731/horizontal-bar-charts-in-pgfplots-point-meta-messes-with-alignment). With this I was able to get this MWE:

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfplotsset{
    TornadoPlot/.style={% Overall settings
        width = 1\textwidth,
    line width=1pt,
    tick style={line width=0.8pt},
    xmin = -50, xmax = 50,
    xtick       = {-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
    xticklabels = {-50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
    xmajorgrids = true,
    minor x tick num = 1,
    tick align = outside,
    xtick pos = left, ytick pos = left,
    xbar, bar shift=0pt,
    height = 7cm,
    enlarge y limits = 0.1, ytick = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6},
    nodes near coords={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    },
    nodes near coords align = {horizontal},
    before end axis/.code={
        \draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis    cs:0,0});
    }           
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[TornadoPlot, legend style={at={(0.975,0.25)}}]
            \addplot[fill=green!40] coordinates{(-3.5,0) (-16,1) (-17.5,2) (-19,3) (-34,4) (-27,5) (-22,6)};
            \addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(4,0) (19,1) (12.5,2) (28.5,3) (34,4) (82,5) (38,6)};
            \legend{upside, downside} 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, one of the bars (82, 5) has a positive x value that is outside the range of the domain of the plot. Can I restrict the length of that bar and force a break, while still displaying the original value of x? I have seen [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88892/pgfplots-bar-plot-spacing-inbetween-bars) for vertical bar-charts, but so far I have not been able to reproduce this for my tornado plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. For details on how to do that, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        TornadoPlot/.style={% Overall settings
            width=\textwidth,
            height=7cm,
            xmin=-50,
            xmax=50,
            line width=1pt,
            tick style={line width=0.8pt},
            xmajorgrids=true,
            minor x tick num=1,
            tick align=outside,
            tick pos=left,
            xbar,
            bar shift=0pt,
            enlarge y limits=0.1,
            ytick distance=1,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % this is the solution to your problem
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % we want the *original* x value and store it in a macro ...
            visualization depends on={rawx \as \rawx},
            % ... which value should be shown in the `nodes near coords'
            nodes near coords={%
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawx}%
            },
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            before end axis/.code={
                \draw  ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:0,0})
                    -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:0,0})
                ;
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            TornadoPlot,
            legend style={at={(0.975,0.25)}},
            % and we want to limit the range of the bars to the axis limits
            restrict x to domain*={
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}
            },
        ]
            \addplot [fill=green!40] coordinates
                {(-3.5,0) (-16,1) (-17.5,2) (-19,3) (-34,4) (-27,5) (-22,6)};
            \addplot [fill=red!40]   coordinates
                {(4,0) (19,1) (12.5,2) (28.5,3) (34,4) (82,5) (38,6)};
            \legend{upside, downside}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]